# Regex ([mb|kb|gb|b|bytes]) does not match 'b' in 'kb' or 'gb' without a + after the braces

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a regular expression that can capture a value and any of mb, kb, gb, bytes that comes after it 
The Regex is:

```
    (?<sizevalue>\p{N}+)(?:\s*)(?<sizetype>[mb|kb|gb|b|bytes])
```

But when given an input "4096 mb", group sizetype matches only 'm' and not 'b'. adding a '+' quantifier after the braces gives the output of grop sizetype as 'mb'. The pattern was compiled with CASE_INSENSITIVE so that was not the issue.
This works

```
   (?<sizevalue>\p{N}+)(?:\s*)(?<sizetype>[mb|kb|gb|b|bytes]+)
```

Ideally shouldn't the first regex match 'mb' completely ?

Comment: You need `( )` where you have `[ ]`.  An expression in square brackets only matches a single character.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use capturing or non-capturing group instead of a character class.

`[mb|kb|gb|b|bytes]` matches only a single charcater from the given list, ie, it may match an `m` or `b` or `|` or `k` or `b`, etc. It won't consider `mb` as a single word and `|` operator inside the character class will looses it's special meaning and matches only a literal `|` symbol. It won't do an OR operation.

```
(?<sizevalue>\p{N}+)(?:\s*)(?<sizetype>(?:mb|kb|gb|b|bytes)\b)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lT3mL1/2)

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<sizevalue>\\p{N}+)(?:\\s*)(?<sizetype>(?:mb|kb|gb|b|bytes)\\b)");
```

Comment: So within the square braces, it matches only the first character in the alternatives and without a '+' quantifier spits out only the first character?

Comment: `[mb|kb|gb|b|bytes]+` matches mb, bytes,gb because all these characters are included in the character class but this also matches `test`, `bg`, `kytes`, etc